# array index error when looping over go routines

Tags: go, goroutine

I am running go routines in a loop for two functions using `sync` to wait until go routines are finished and then running a normal function outside the loop like:

```
func fetchStudentsAndTeachers(db *sqlx.DB, token string) {
    var students Students
    var teachers Teachers
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    // defer wg.Wait()
    tch := make(chan Teachers)
    schoolList := fetchActiveOrganization(DB)
    std := make(chan Students)
    for key, value := range schoolList {
        value2 := value
        fmt.Println(key, ":", value)
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            std <- fetchStudentsFromSchool(wg, value2.CleverSchoolID, token)
        }()
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            tch <- fetchTeachersFromSchool(wg, value2.CleverSchoolID, token)
        }()
        students = <-std
        // teachers = <-tch
    }
    wg.Wait() // It panics after this point
    UpdateOrganizationsAndUsers(DB)
    close(std)
    close(tch)
    fmt.Println(students)
    fmt.Println(teachers)
}
```

Now problem is when I come out of loop is is giving me index out of bound error. I checked is using delve debugger on `wg.Wait()` After forwarding the control of debugger from `wg.Wait()`. It panics saying:

> panic: runtime error: index out of range

**(Edited)**
Note: This problem is due to the loop iterates one time and run the routine which process databases. But somehow the loop iterate again before the routines completes which is causing the error. What should I do to complete both routines before next iteration.

Comment: can you please look at the stact trace data on panic for checking which lines and routines causes this error!

Comment: yes see the comment on line `wg.Wait()`

Comment: Does your code panic at `wg.Wait` or *after* it on the subsequent line? e.g. `UpdateOrganizationsAndUsers`?

Comment: on `wg.Wait()` it never executes `UpdateOrganizationsAndUsers`

Comment: @Himanshu Do you know which part of the code is indexing out of range? Can you provide the full stack trace so we can see the file+line number of the bug.

Comment: Actually it is showing error in `fetchTeachersFromSchool` function used in go routines now I am just trying to look at the debugger.

Comment: The code you posted is not the reason for the panic, it is somewher else in your code. In its current form, this question is off-topic.

Comment: @icza may be but thanks for your valuable time. I was about to upvote your answer. Because of your effort. I am really thankful. Since I am stuck I am just trying to figure out what is the reason behind the error. I have upvoted your another answer. I know you are genius in golang thanks again. I will come back with my actual issue

Comment: @Himanshu I removed my answer because it didn't solve your issue. If you can post a code that itself reproduces the error, we can solve it and leave an answer that is useful for others.

Comment: yes I am learning something actually the answer that you have posted has one  thing that i noticed. That the go routines not executed completed and the iterates which causes it to break since the data taht is passed in the loop is changed before fetching another data from an api using that token.

Comment: @icza. I haved edited my question. Please take a look what is the actual problem

Comment: @mkopriva. Please look at the edited question which is causing the error.

Comment: @Himanshu Try placing wg.Wait inside the loop as the last statement.

Comment: @Himanshu Or uncomment `teachers = <-tch`, this should block until `fetchTeachersFromSchool` is done.

Comment: @Himanshu *"s̶o̶m̶e̶h̶o̶w̶  the loop iterate again before the routines completes"* that's the purpose of goroutines, to allow code to run concurrently, there is nothing suprising about the loop executing subsequent iterations if you don't syncronize the goroutines inside it (with channels or waitgroups).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170787/discussion-between-himanshu-and-mkopriva).

Comment: @icza the error was due to transactions which is not executing so thanks for your help. I also learned something about go routines that it will block every time if we use channels. Else we can use `wg.Wait()` outside of loop body.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks for your time and help. Your idea to run functions without go routines helped me.

Comment: @Himanshu I'm glad it worked out. (Btw, I also edited my answer to further simplify the concurrent work.)

Comment: I will definitely read it to understand concurrency better. One thing I noticed is that if your creating concurrent functions to work with database transactions which will not complete until it is committed. It is better to use channels to signal and wait

Answer (score 1):

If you want the 2 worker goroutines to finish before the next iteration starts, simply move the `wg.Wait()` call to the end of the loop body:

```
for key, value := range schoolList {
    value2 := value
    fmt.Println(key, ":", value)
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        std <- fetchStudentsFromSchool(wg, value2.CleverSchoolID, token)
    }()
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        tch <- fetchTeachersFromSchool(wg, value2.CleverSchoolID, token)
    }()
    students = <-std
    teachers = <-tch
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Also note that if you're already using channels to deliver the goroutine results, and if no one else uses the `std` and `tch` channels, `WaitGroup` is not even needed:

```
for key, value := range schoolList {
    value2 := value
    fmt.Println(key, ":", value)
    go func() {
        std <- fetchStudentsFromSchool(wg, value2.CleverSchoolID, token)
    }()
    go func() {
        tch <- fetchTeachersFromSchool(wg, value2.CleverSchoolID, token)
    }()
    students = <-std
    teachers = <-tch
}
```

This is enough because the next iteration can only start if both receiving from `std` and `tch` are completed, but those can only happen if the worker goroutines do their job and send the result on these channels.

Now if we think about what this does: the loop's goroutine waits for 2 worker goroutines to finish their work and then proceed (to the next iteration). While the 2 workers work, it just waits.

We can simplify and improve this by doing 1 worker's job in the loop's goroutine, and when done, wait for the single worker to also finish (if not yet finished).

This is how it could look like:

```
for key, value := range schoolList {
    value2 := value
    fmt.Println(key, ":", value)
    go func() {
        std <- fetchStudentsFromSchool(wg, value2.CleverSchoolID, token)
    }()
    teachers = fetchTeachersFromSchool(wg, value2.CleverSchoolID, token)
    students = <-std
}
```

We simply fetch teachers in the loop's goroutine, and only fetch students in a concurrent goroutine. This has the same effect (students and teachers are fetched concurrently), with less overhead and cleaner code.

Also note that since you now have synchronization to not start the next iteration until the workers finish, you do not need to make a copy of the loop variable: it will not be modified during the workers' lifetime. So you may simply use:

```
for key, value := range schoolList {
    fmt.Println(key, ":", value)
    go func() {
        std <- fetchStudentsFromSchool(wg, value.CleverSchoolID, token)
    }()
    teachers = fetchTeachersFromSchool(wg, value.CleverSchoolID, token)
    students = <-std
}
```

(This applies to the solution with waitgroup too.)

Comment: Thanks for reply instantly but it still panics with same error. Please check an edit

Comment: I have edited my question. with a code where if i remove one of go routine it does not show any error.

Comment: I have changed with wg.Done. But it is something else. Let me edit my question with wg.done()

Comment: I am not getting why it is working when i remove one of go routines inside for loop.

Comment: yes I am generating a minimal code. yes I am receiving from both channels and its then creating a slice of students and teachers

Comment: This is [minimal](https://play.golang.org/p/UJuQfbbvJf3). But this is working fine.

Comment: yes I know working code will not help. I am trying on more round using debugger actually the code is many lines of code since it includes database transactions too.

Comment: @Himanshu Edited and undeleted my answer. Removing my old comments from here (suggesting to do the same).